# Single Sign On - Workflow

Tags: php, frameworks, single-sign-on

It was proposed to develop an SSO, but I'm not very knowledgeable about it.
Tell me if this makes sense and where to start?

I have 3 apps

> A - Developed in Python (Django); B - Developed in PHP (Phalcon); C -
>   Developed in PHP (Yii2);

The idea is to have a simple and unique "login page" and that when you 
log in on this page with Active Directory (Windows) can jump to A, B, or C 
without manual re-signing.

How will the "login page" communicate with other
apps in different languages ​​/ frameworks?

Comment: Look into Oauth2

Comment: I have SSO server/client software here:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/sso-server  While the SSO client is the preferred integration method, it also supports incoming OAuth2 and has namespace support for seamless sign-in to multiple applications.